# Error on booting Ubuntu PXE-M0F

Tags: 14.04, usb, usb-drive

This is my first time to install Ubuntu, I used PendriveLinux to install Ubuntu 15.10 on a USB Drive, changed the BIOS to boot from the USB drive first and when the computer boots it displays the following error message:

Realtek PCIe FE Family Controller Series v1.23 (07/28/10)
PXE-E61: Media test failure, check cable

PXE-M0F: Exiting PXE ROM.
Operating System not found

This HD has already Windows 7 and I was planning to install a fresh Ubuntu OS removing Windows 7 completely, I searched and found a few threads talking about the same error but it seems all of such errors happen after the OS is installed and then rebooted while in my case I am not even given the option to install the OS

I even tried it on another computer and it seems it is giving a similar error.
Appreciate your advice?

Note: I used the steps in this link to prepare the USB bootable drive (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStickQuick) and under step 1 I choose 'ubuntu'

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After different trials I was able to find out the problem, it seems that the downloaded ISO file was not complete although Chrome Download Manager has mentioned that the download was complete, I downloaded a fresh copy, checked it with the MD5 Checksum and it seems to be working now, at least I can see now the Ubuntu initial installation menu

I am facing another issue though and I have been searching for a resolution for some time now so probably I will post another question related to this other issue